# loading json images into tabs with kineticjs

Tags: javascript, json, tabs, kineticjs

I am not using any *jQuery*. I have three tabs with three different images one in each tab and the opportunity to write a different text in each image. I have used only one stage, added one image layer where I add the images. I have just changed the `imageObj.src` for each tab(in order to insert different images).

What I want to achieve is to go back to a tab and find the image with the text that was set there before. Thus, I have saved that stage as a `stage.toJson()` and I get the right json string. When I reload it in a newstage, it works (shows me the correct image with text) but then crashes just after that for some reason:

```
case '1':   // case tab 1   
 stage.removeChildren();

 if(!json==""){             
    imageObj.src = 'image url';  
    var newstage = Kinetic.Node.create(json,'tabscontent');
    imageObj.onload = function() {
       newstage.get('.shirtimg')[0].setImage(imageObj);
       newstage.draw();     
    }  
 }                                                                          

break;
```

Any idea at all? Thnx.

Comment: What is the error log in console? Apart from that you can basically have 3 image objects, one for each tab. Show and hide as per the clicked tab. If you can add your code to a fiddle, I might be able to edit it for you

Comment: Having trouble to create a fiddle at the moment. However, my source is:                                                           [link](http://www.my-html-codes.com/javascript-tabs-html-5-css3) .         The console shows me the following error:                                                    TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

document.getElementById("tabpage_" + current).style.display="none";                                     It doesn't recognize the "tabpage_" + current  var. Trying to work on it.

Comment: your source link does not have any KineticJS related code

Comment: I know. That code works perfectly fine until I save the tab content(stage) in a json string and load it. There it gets stuck, when I go back to a saved stage.

Comment: Well what you have there is quite standard JavaScript and CSS tabs work, so unless you add KineticJS code and show the error, I'm afraid its hard to solve your problem

Comment: Managed to create a fiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/bouk/z4MTG/4/  Obviously the image src cannot be set because of json domain permission issues.  I added just the relevant part of the code to my problem.  Hope it creates the idea  anyway. Thnx

Comment: the fiddle is not correct, loads of errors. Try pressing the add - doesnt work. Neither is the code for switching tabs... In any case, I'd still recommend not to remove children and recreate tabs everytime. Simply make 3 image objects and corresponding 3 text objects and show them depending on the chosen tab.

Comment: Hey Ani, you cannot add the text because there is no image to add it to. It is a big piece of code, I just send that part to give you a general idea. Working on your advice now. Thanks